# Merge eager loading of child entities with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to do the following things with EF and I'm not sure it's possible. I've a entity with multiple child entities. Because I've to include all these entities in multiple queries, I use this extension method :

```
public static IQueryable<Model.CourseRegistration> DefaultInclude(this IQueryable<Model.CourseRegistration> cr)
{
  return cr.Include(r => r.Course)
           .Include(r => r.Course.CourseDescription)
           .Include(r => r.Course.CourseType)
           .Include(r => r.Course.Department)
           .Include(r => r.Course.Teacher)
           .Include(r => r.Student)
           .Include(r => r.Results);
}
```

Using this, I can do `db.CourseRegistrations.DefaultInclude().ToList()` and it works perfectly. Now, I've another entity that include a navigation property on a collection of CourseRegistration. To eager load all the child entities, I use the following extension :

```
public static IQueryable<Model.Student> DefaultInclude(this IQueryable<Model.Student> cr)
{
    return cr.Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Results))
             .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Course))
             .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Course.CourseDescription))
             .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Course.CourseType))
             .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Course.Department))
             .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(s => s.Course.Teacher));
}
```

As you can see, most of the code is adding the same entities as the first method. To reduce duplication, I tried the following thing :

```
public static IQueryable<Model.Student> DefaultInclude(this IQueryable<Model.Student> cr)
{
    return cr.Include(r => r.Courses.AsQueryable().DefaultInclude());
}
```

Unfortunatly, EF doesn't like it and return an error : ***"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties."***.

Any idea if it's possible to "merge" include list from 2 entities ?

Thanks.